# updating android widget on different times

Tags: android, android-widget

I followed a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) to create a widget, I want to update widget view on different times a day time for updating is not constant, So how can I do that,

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do so I created an array of times, at which I want update my widget, and set `Repeating AlarmManager` with interval of 1day, as per my requirement, for each time of array, that worked for me.